# AngularJS recover user session - cookies or token

Tags: angularjs, session, authentication, cookies

I'm developing an `AngularJS` app used by third part applications. The third part application and my AngularJS application have a common database where users preferences/credentials are stored. User can login from the third part application and, by redirecting the user into my application, I need to **maintain the user logged in**, without asking a new authentication procedure.
I can't use cookies because the two applications are in two different domains.
I can't pass a session TOKEN (correspondant to the user logged iin) in query parameters due to man in the middle risks.

Is it possible to make a POST request to an angularJS page? Third part app call my AngularJS login page POSTing a token in the body request. My app take the token, verifyies it and log-in the user.

**Constraints:**

1. *App in different domains;*
2. *Maintain user logged in;*
3. *No sharing cookies;*
4. *Try to prevent man in the middle;*
5. *No query parameters;*
6. *HTTPS protocol;*
7. *web based applications.*

Am I missing something in the https protocols/sharing sessions?

Are there other solutions supported by AngularJS?

How can I redirect the user from one application to another and maintaining the user logged in in a simple way? Is there a simple flow I haven't figured out?

AngularJS is based on REST api communications. I can ask for a webpage (GET the webpage), but I can't make a POST to an AngularJS page. Is there a way to pass/share some values from the first application to my second app in a secure way?

Comment: Why do you care about a man in the middle since you're using HTTPS? All the man in the middle would see would be encrypted traffic.

Comment: Send it in the the headers of all rest calls.

Comment: Why are you not using something like oath?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure: "Everything in the HTTPS message is encrypted, including the headers, and the request/response load. [...] the attacker can only know the fact that a connection is taking place between the two parties, already known to him, the domain name and IP addresses." So the URL is encrypted.

Comment: thanks you. Query parameters are encrypted! My lack of knowledge!